# Как должен меняться <title> страницы в header.php?

Tags: php, html, layout

В моем шаблоне сайта следующая структура

```
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
Контент страницы
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

В фаиле header.php прописаны фаилы стилей и другие стандартные настройки, в том числе тэг

```
<title></title>
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы содержимое тэга «title» менялось в зависимости от того, на какой странице находится пользователь? Вот мой код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>My website title – Main Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```

Спасибо

Comment: очевидно, что "контент страницы" надо готовить до вызова header.php почитать хотя бы http://phpfaq.ru/tech/tpl

Comment: Используйре шаблонизаторы для решения своей задачи, не мешайте `html` и `php` код. Попробуйте `Twig` или `Blade`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не получится, так как headers.php идет раньше содержимого и уже собран на момент "рендеринга".

Можно хранить еще один "файлик", в котором будет база с заголовками, а ваш header.php  будет подгружать заголовки в зависимости от url или еще в какой-то зависимости, массивом или объектом или еще как-то!

Так-же можно это сделать средствами js, то-есть  в теле главного шаблона, будет меняться переменная отвечающая за заголовок, а js будет выставлять заголовок после полной загрузки страницы!

Вот, посмотрите пример задания значения title. Объявленная переменная $title может быть задана как в header.php, так и до header.php, т.е. там, где вы подключаете этот файл.

```
<?php

$title =" My website title – Main Page";

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title><?=$title ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```

Или так.

```
<?php

$title =" My website title – Main Page";

include("header.php");
```

Как упоминалось выше, способ определения значения $title может быть любым:

- через условия if, switch-case в сравнении с URL или какими-то другими аргументами;
- через ассоциативный массив $titles = ['url_1' => 'Заголовок'];
- через БД (получать имя страницы по url);
- генерировать рандомно;
- передавать url в заголовок =), и т.п.

Однако в ряде случаев вы должны проверять на валидность url, чтобы не было выполнено атаки на страницу.

Comment: Господи, какой кошмар. Какой ещё "файлик"? Какие атаки? Какой яваскрипт? Какой url? П вдруг кроме тайтла надо будет что-то еще писать, мета теги например? еще один файлик? А если тайтл из БД берется?

Comment: @Ипатьев Человек явно только вникает в PHP, никакие шаблонизаторы ему не известны и возможно будут непонятны, т.к. и банальное использование переменных в PHP вызвало затруднение.

Comment: @OlegDmitrochenko дело тут не в шаблонизаторах, а в принципе который они реализуют. ему надо не с тайтлом колупаться, как вы тут советуете (что при его структуре само по себе нереализуемо) а **всю логику перемещать в начало скрипта**. Всю. а между хидером и футером оставлять только вывод. И после этого вопрос с тайтлом отпадет сам собой.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии и советы!

Comment: ооо сколько исправлений моего ответа )))))  а "файлик" - это я назвал, так как может быть как js/php так и просто любой файл который будет своего рода хранилищем настроек. 
ПО поводу если еще написать и если будет то да еще, для этого уже другой вопрос и в рамках другого  вопроса и решения  реализовываться !

Тут был вопрос по выводу  заголовка страницы, Олег правильно  добавил пример, спасибо. а для всего остальное уже есть другое.  как средства так и решения ! не нужно вплетать и додумывать!